# Radiobuttonlist in Asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

My problem is i want to store Practical Monthly plan in database as per my requirement i have to display Monthly and `3 Month's Plan` in webform please help me i need the code with C#

```
 RadioButtonList ID="rbtnlistProgramPlans" runat="server"
      asp:ListItem Text="Practical Monthly Plan" Value="0"   **Monthly**   asp:ListItem
            asp:ListItem Text="Practical 3 Month's Plan" Value="1"   **3 Month's**   asp:ListItem
```

Monthly and 3 Month's are displayed in webform for user but i want to store which radiobuttonlist is selected that text="Practical Monthly Plan"..like that help me 
I am new asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Your current listitem in radiobuttonlist is

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Practical Monthly Plan" Value="0">Monthly</asp:ListItem>
```

but it should be like...

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Practical Monthly Plan" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
```

as text between starting `<asp:ListItem> and </asp:ListItem>` consider as Displaying text and `override Text property of listitem`

Answer (score 1):

Code ex:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id=RadioButtonList1 runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Practical Monthly Plan" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Practical 3 Monthly Plan" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Practical X Monthly Plan" Value="X"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

[more info from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx)